# Weird error when launching VLC from command line

Tags: vlc, qt

Does anyone know how to solve this error? I tried viewing the content of the files in question, but I can only see weird characters.

```
cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so' (/usr/lib/libEGL.so.1: undefined symbol: _mali_clz_lut)
```

Comment: Many forums with this kind of error point to Google Earth, have you installed it recently?

Comment: I read that, I don't have Google Earth. I deleted everything qt4 related before reinstalling vlc (ldconfig -p | grep libQt had an empty output).

Answer (score 0):

**This may be a bad idea. Things might go from bad to worse.**

You can try doing a `sudo apt-get purge libqt*`

It will ask you to confirm packages to remove under 'The following packages will be REMOVED:'. Copy those packages in a text file somewhere because we will re-install them again. Confirm and remove them.

Next run a `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Then go to your /home/.config folder and delete the vlc folder in there.

Then reinstall the core packages like ubuntu-desktop, totem and vlc and see whether it will work this time.

I tried this (I didn't confirm though) and the packages that were to be removed included: unity-2d, vlc, skype, qbittorrent, totem, ubuntu-desktop, speedcrunch and alot of qt plugins.